# Hibernate join fetch

Tags: java, hibernate

I have implemented the following example  in this blog  https://www.tutorialandexample.com/hibernate-n-1-select-problem/  but I am not happy with the output that I am getting. I am displaying the output which shows Department details and Employee details printed as twice . I want to get the Department details and Employee details to be displayed only once . Any Suggestions ?

The size of depart List object is 4 but actually it must be 2 .

output :

```
Department details:::::
20  IT
Employees details::::::
21  jyotika
22  shubham
Department details:::::
20  IT
Employees details::::::
21  jyotika
22  shubham
Department details:::::
23  Accounts
Employees details::::::
24  nihal
25  neha
Department details:::::
23  Accounts
Employees details::::::
24  nihal
25  neha
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then modify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Provide result transformer `Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` in query

```
List depart= sess.createQuery("From Department", Department.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).getResultList();
```